# Predicting baseline cumulative hazard using predict.coxph in r

Tags: r, predict, survival-analysis, cox-regression, hazard

My aim is to predict (predict cumulative hazard for a new observation from the fitted model below) the cumulative hazard value from the time scale 0 to the start time from the fitted model.

I have fitted the cox model using 2 times (start time which is not equal to 0 and end time). So then I can find the difference between cumulative hazard at the end time(i.e. cumulative hazard from 0 to end time, which I have already calculated using the same fitted model) and the cumulative hazard at the start time (i.e. cumulative hazard from 0 to end time, which I want to calculate here) which will ultimately give the cum haz between start and end time of each observation.

So for getting the expected number of events I've used `predict(coxph(), newdata, type= "expected")` .

The data I have used is as follows:

```
N <- 10^4 # population
H <- within(data.frame(start_time=runif(N, 0, 50), x1=rnorm(N, 2, 1), x2=rnorm(N, -2, 1)), {
  lp <-   0.05*x1 + 0.2*x2 
  Tm <- qweibull(runif(N,pweibull(start_time,shape = 7.5, scale = 84*exp(-lp/7.5)),1), shape=7.5, scale=84*exp(-lp/7.5))
  Cens1 <- 100
  event_time <- pmin(Tm,Cens1)
  status <- as.numeric(event_time == Tm)})
```

and the code for prediction is:

```
H$X <- rep(1,nrow(H))
D = coxph(Surv(start_time, event_time, status) ~ X, data =  H, x = TRUE )
pred2 <- predict(D, newdata = data.frame(start_time = rep(0,nrow(H)),event_time = H$start_time, status = rep(0,nrow(H)), X = rep(1, nrow(H))), type = "expected")
```

But the `pred2` only results in "NA" values. Can someone point out whether there is any mistake in my idea or in the code

Please let me know if any more further clarification is required.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Please provide `d`.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've corrected the code and I think it's reproducible now. Can you try it now. Let me know if there is anymore correction needed

Comment: The point of a Cox model is to estimate <bold>relative</bold> hazards. It's always relative to hypothetical cases with a mean value of the covariates. You are asking it to estimate relative hazards with nothing to compare risks to since there are no covariates. If all you want is a KM curve then `cph` is the wrong function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, it's just a quick trick which I'm not sure will work always.
If I use the following line before the `predict()` function:

`D$coefficients["X"] <- 0`

But, I am getting proper values which checked using the `nelsonaalen()` function which doesn't accept start time (or two variable at a time)

Let me know if there's any other proper way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues. First, you run into an issue because when you specify `~1`,which means fitting an intercept only model with no coefficients. so all your predictions will give you one value?

```
library(survival)
D <- coxph(Surv(H$start_time, H$event_time, H$status) ~ 1, x = TRUE )
names(D)
 [1] "loglik"            "linear.predictors" "method"           
 [4] "residuals"         "n"                 "nevent"           
 [7] "terms"             "assign"            "concordance"      
[10] "x"                 "y"                 "timefix"          
[13] "formula"           "call"  

table(predict(D))

    0 
10000
```

I don't think that makes a lot of sense, and hence you run into all the errors. So you need to predict with independent variables that are using in the regression for example:

```
D <- coxph(Surv(start_time,event_time,status) ~ x1+x2, data=H )
pred2 <- predict(D, newdata = data.frame(t_0 = rep(0,nrow(H)),time = H$start_time, event_M = rep(0,nrow(H)), X = rep(1, nrow(H))), type = "expected")

predict(D,newdata=data.frame(x1=runif(10,0,1),x2=runif(10,-1,1)))
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
0.3033206 0.4213120 0.3952827 0.3879701 0.4798670 0.2170032 0.3385253 0.4141698 
        9        10 
0.3690579 0.4128084
```

When you fit a model with all X=1, this gives you all NAs because there is already an intercept, which makes this variable redundant. You can check:

```
H$X = 1
D <- coxph(Surv(start_time, event_time, status) ~ X,data=H)

Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(start_time, event_time, status) ~ X, data = H)

  coef exp(coef) se(coef)  z  p
X   NA        NA        0 NA NA
```

It only works when X is an actual variable in the fitted data, so I use an example with 2 covariates:

```
H$X = runif(nrow(H))
D <- coxph(Surv(start_time, event_time, status) ~ X + x1,data=H)
```

And you can predict by for example fixing X at 1 and varying x1:

```
predict(D,newdata=data.frame(X=1,x1=c(0.1,0.2,0.3)))
         1          2          3 
-0.1132548 -0.1084592 -0.1036637
```

or X at 2:

```
predict(D,newdata=data.frame(X=2,x1=c(0.1,0.2,0.3)))
                 1          2          3 
-0.1579480 -0.1531524 -0.1483568
```

Comment: As in the question I want to estimate the baseline cumulative hazard without the effect of covariates and when I added one more variable ```H$X = rep(1, nrow(H))```  and fitted the model using ```D = coxph(Surv(start_time, event_time, status) ~ X, data =  H, x = TRUE )``` the code is running without any error but I am getting "NA" values as result. I am not sure whether my concept is right. PS: I have modified the code just now and I think you won't encounter error in between (I have explained what I want in it bit more detailed in the question as well)

Comment: In the data you put into the model, X is all one. How is this different from fitting a model ```coxph(Surv(start_time, event_time, status) ~ 1``` ? You now run into an error because you have the intercept too, making X redundant

Comment: Can you actually fit the model with sensible data? I have updated my answer. It seems like it's no longer a programming question. Perhaps you can check this out first before posting? https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendices/Appendix-Cox-Regression.pdf